# Primary script unknown nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx. I try to deploy it on kubernetes. But I get :

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 10.0.1.1, server: , request:
>   "GET /app.php/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:9000", host:

I have no idea how to resolve this
And when I get the url :

> File not found.

Here my config file :

```
server {
    listen  80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /srv/webroot/web;
    index app.php;

    client_max_body_size 30M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony;
    }

    location ~ /app_dev.php/ {
        try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony_dev;
    }

    location @pass_to_symfony{
        rewrite ^ /app.php?$request_uri last;
    }

    location @pass_to_symfony_dev{
        rewrite ^ /app_dev.php?$request_uri last;
    }

    location ~ ^/app(_dev)?\.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

My project is on symfony

Comment: Trailing slash on the get after the PHP looks fishy to me : ""GET /app.php/"

Comment: like that ?     location ~ ^/app(_dev)?\.php {

Comment: So, what is in `/srv/webroot/web/app.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Where a PHP URI includes path info, you will need to use a `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive (or something similar) to separate the actual script name (e.g. `/app.php`) from the path info appended to it (e.g. `/`).

```
location ~ ^/app(_dev)?\.php($|/) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

See [this example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm) for details.